# Creation of checkbox parameter

Tags: abap

Normal creation of checkbox:

PARAMETERS : p_check TYPE char1 AS CHECKBOX.

Without using this will it is possible to declare the parameter as checkbox?

Comment: Why would you want to obfuscate the fact that you're creating a checkbox in the first place...?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible.

PARAMETERS : p_check TYPE boole_d.

This will display the parameter as check box.

Comment: Also, it's not EWM-specific and works on all ABAP-based systems

Answer (score 0):

```
    PARAMETERS : p_check TYPE flag.
    PARAMETERS : p_check TYPE boole_d.
```

This will also display a check box on the screen.

So any domain which is having a length of single character and with a value range of fixed values as 'X' and blank/space helps us to display the parameter as check box.

Here in this case flag data element is assigned to domain 'flag' with data length single character and value range having 'X' and blank.

For boole_d it is assigned to domain 'boole' having the properties mentioned as above.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox can be created in Dynpro Painter too. Without coding, you can drag and drop there.